# Does anybody knows why i have a wifi network authentication loop in ubuntu-20.4?

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking

I have a 10 years old laptop with Ubuntu(updated) and everything it seems to work perfect until now. My WiFi network disconnects itself randomly and starts asking for password.
In first place this problem occurs while I was connected for 5-10 minutes. But now it’s again and again without connection. Here is some info:

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak] [8086:0084]
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 BGN [8086:1315]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi


inxi -Fxz
System:
  Kernel: 5.4.0-58-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.3.0 
  Desktop: Gnome 3.36.4 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Hewlett-Packard product: HP ProBook 4510s v: F.0D 
  serial: <filter> 
  Mobo: Hewlett-Packard model: 3074 v: KBC Version 24.0D serial: <filter> 
  BIOS: Hewlett-Packard v: 68PZI Ver. F.0D date: 09/10/2009 
CPU:
  Topology: Dual Core model: Intel Core2 Duo T6670 bits: 64 type: MCP 
  arch: Penryn rev: A L2 cache: 2048 KiB 
  flags: lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 8778 
  Speed: 1197 MHz min/max: 1200/2201 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1229 2: 1290 
Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD RV710/M92 [Mobility Radeon HD 4330/4350/4550] 
  vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: radeon v: kernel bus ID: 01:00.0 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: radeon 
  resolution: 1280x1024~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: AMD RV710 (DRM 2.50.0 / 5.4.0-58-generic LLVM 10.0.0) 
  v: 3.3 Mesa 20.0.8 direct render: Yes 
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel 82801I HD Audio vendor: Hewlett-Packard 
  driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 00:1b.0 
  Device-2: AMD RV710/730 HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 4000 series] 
  driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 01:00.1 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-58-generic 
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak] driver: iwlwifi 



  v: kernel port: 7000 bus ID: 03:00.0 
  IF: wlp3s0 state: up mac: <filter> 
  Device-2: Marvell 88E8072 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet vendor: Hewlett-Packard 
  driver: sky2 v: 1.30 port: 2000 bus ID: 86:00.0 
  IF: ens5 state: down mac: <filter> 
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 465.76 GiB used: 19.10 GiB (4.1%) 
  ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Seagate model: ST9500420AS size: 465.76 GiB 
  temp: 31 C 
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 457.45 GiB used: 19.10 GiB (4.2%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda1 
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 54.0 C mobo: 39.0 C 
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:
  Processes: 213 Uptime: 14m Memory: 3.81 GiB used: 2.24 GiB (58.8%) 
  Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 9.3.0 Shell: bash v: 5.0.17 
  inxi: 3.0.38
```

I've tried to update so last version, reinstall network manager, unable ipv6, install iwlwifi dkms and a lot of things I even don't know what they were for but the problem is still there. I don't even touch anything of my router acces point. Although I've try the steps are published in this link https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=268914

Here it is the `journalctl -b -u NetworkManager -u wpa_supplicant` output:

```
-- Logs begin at Mon 2020-01-06 17:35:02 CET, end at Tue 2020-12-22 19:32:07 CET. --
dic 22 18:48:31 hellnhell-HP-ProBook-4510s systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager...
dic 22 18:48:31 hellnhell-HP-ProBook-4510s systemd[1]: Starting WPA supplicant...
dic 22 18:48:42 hellnhell-HP-ProBook-4510s wpa_supplicant[968]: Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
dic 22 18:48:42 hellnhell-HP-ProBook-4510s systemd[1]: Started WPA supplicant.
dic 22 18:48:44 hellnhell-HP-ProBook-4510s NetworkManager[932]: <info>  [1608659324.5867] NetworkManager (version 1.22.10) is start>
dic 22 18:48:44 hellnhell-HP-ProBook-4510s NetworkManager[932]: <info>  [1608659324.5868] Read config: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkM>
dic 22 18:48:44 hellnhell-HP-ProBook-4510s systemd[1]: Started Network Manager.
dic 22 18:48:44 hellnhell-HP-ProBook-4510s NetworkManager[932]: <info>  [1608659324.7885] bus-manager: acquired D-Bus service "org.>
dic 22 18:48:44 hellnhell-HP-ProBook-4510s NetworkManager[932]: <info>  [1608659324.9755] manager[0x5560d6c67000]: monitoring kerne>
dic 22 18:48:44 hellnhell-HP-ProBook-4510s NetworkManager[932]: <info>  [1608659324.9760] monitoring ifupdown state file '/run/netw>
dic 22 18:48:46 hellnhell-HP-ProBook-4510s NetworkManager[932]: <info>  [1608659326.2491] hostname: hostname: using hostnamed
dic 22 18:48:46 hellnhell-HP-ProBook-4510s NetworkManager[932]: <info>  [1608659326.2491] hostname: hostname changed from (none) to>
dic 22 18:48:46 hellnhell-HP-ProBook-4510s NetworkManager[932]: <info>  [1608659326.2496] dns-mgr[0x5560d6c4c290]: init: dns=system>
dic 22 18:48:46 hellnhell-HP-ProBook-4510s NetworkManager[932]: <info>  [1608659326.2508] rfkill1: found Wi-Fi radio killswitch (at>
dic 22 18:48:46 hellnhell-HP-ProBook-4510s NetworkManager[932]: <info>  [1608659326.2511] rfkill0: found Wi-Fi radio killswitch (at>
dic 22 18:48:46 hellnhell-HP-ProBook-4510s NetworkManager[932]: <info>  [1608659326.2628] manager[0x5560d6c67000]: rfkill: Wi-Fi ha>
dic 22 18:48:46 hellnhell-HP-ProBook-4510s NetworkManager[932]: <info>  [1608659326.2633] manager[0x5560d6c67000]: rfkill: WWAN har>
dic 22 18:48:47 hellnhell-HP-ProBook-4510s NetworkManager[932]: <info>  [1608659327.5108] Loaded device plugin: NMWifiFactory (/usr>
dic 22 18:48:48 hellnhell-HP-ProBook-4510s NetworkManager[932]: <info>  [1608659328.0070] Loaded device plugin: NMTeamFactory (/usr>
dic 22 18:48:48 hellnhell-HP-ProBook-4510s NetworkManager[932]: <info>  [1608659328.2411] Loaded device plugin: NMAtmManager (/usr/>
dic 22 18:48:48 hellnhell-HP-ProBook-4510s NetworkManager[932]: <info>  [1608659328.4235] Loaded device plugin: NMWwanFactory (/usr>
dic 22 18:48:50 hellnhell-HP-ProBook-4510s NetworkManager[932]: <info>  [1608659330.5545] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/us>
dic 22 18:48:50 hellnhell-HP-ProBook-4510s NetworkManager[932]: <info>  [1608659330.5552] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi enabled by radio k>
dic 22 18:48:50 hellnhell-HP-ProBook-4510s NetworkManager[932]: <info>  [1608659330.5555] manager: rfkill: WWAN enabled by radio ki>
dic 22 18:48:50 hellnhell-HP-ProBook-4510s NetworkManager[932]: <info>  [1608659330.5557] manager: Networking is enabled by state f>
dic 22 18:48:50 hellnhell-HP-ProBook-4510s NetworkManager[932]: <info>  [1608659330.5560] dhcp-init: Using DHCP client 'internal'
dic 22 18:48:51 hellnhell-HP-ProBook-4510s NetworkManager[932]: <info>  [1608659331.0838] settings: Loaded settings plugin: ifupdow>
dic 22 18:48:51 hellnhell-HP-ProBook-4510s NetworkManager[932]: <info>  [1608659331.0838] settings: Loaded settings plugin: keyfile>
dic 22 18:48:51 hellnhell-HP-ProBook-4510s NetworkManager[932]: <info>  [1608659331.0839] ifupdown: management mode: unmanaged
dic 22 18:48:51 hellnhell-HP-ProBook-4510s NetworkManager[932]: <info>  [1608659331.1868] ifupdown:       interface-parser: parsing>
dic 22 18:48:51 hellnhell-HP-ProBook-4510s NetworkManager[932]: <info>  [1608659331.3090] ifupdown:       interface-parser: finishe>
dic 22 18:48:52 hellnhell-HP-ProBook-4510s NetworkManager[932]: <info>  [1608659332.7450] device (lo): carrier: link connected
dic 22 18:48:52 hellnhell-HP-ProBook-4510s NetworkManager[932]: <info>  [1608659332.7456] manager: (lo): new Generic device (/org/f>
dic 22 18:48:52 hellnhell-HP-ProBook-4510s NetworkManager[932]: <info>  [1608659332.7525] manager: (ens5): new Ethernet device (/or>
dic 22 18:48:52 hellnhell-HP-ProBook-4510s NetworkManager[932]: <info>  [1608659332.9988] settings: (ens5): created default wired c>
dic 22 18:48:53 hellnhell-HP-ProBook-4510s NetworkManager[932]: <info>  [1608659333.0023] device (ens5): state change: unmanaged ->>
dic 22 18:48:53 hellnhell-HP-ProBook-4510s NetworkManager[932]: <info>  [1608659333.0124] manager: (wlp3s0): new 802.11 Wi-Fi devic>
dic 22 18:48:53 hellnhell-HP-ProBook-4510s NetworkManager[932]: <info>  [1608659333.0146] device (wlp3s0): state change: unmanaged >
dic 22 18:48:53 hellnhell-HP-ProBook-4510s NetworkManager[932]: <warn>  [1608659333.4942] Error: failed to open /run/network/ifstate
dic 22 18:48:53 hellnhell-HP-ProBook-4510s NetworkManager[932]: <info>  [1608659333.6245] modem-manager: ModemManager available
dic 22 18:48:53 hellnhell-HP-ProBook-4510s NetworkManager[932]: <info>  [1608659333.6334] supplicant: wpa_supplicant running
dic 22 18:48:53 hellnhell-HP-ProBook-4510s NetworkManager[932]: <info>  [1608659333.6335] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface sta>
dic 22 18:48:54 hellnhell-HP-ProBook-4510s wpa_supplicant[968]: dbus: fill_dict_with_properties dbus_interface=fi.w1.wpa_supplicant>
dic 22 18:48:54 hellnhell-HP-ProBook-4510s NetworkManager[932]: <info>  [1608659334.1853] sup-iface[0x5560d6c75120,wlp3s0]: support>
dic 22 18:48:54 hellnhell-HP-ProBook-4510s NetworkManager[932]: <info>  [1608659334.1872] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface sta>
dic 22 18:48:54 hellnhell-HP-ProBook-4510s NetworkManager[932]: <info>  [1608659334.1877] device (wlp3s0): state change: unavailabl>
dic 22 18:48:59 hellnhell-HP-ProBook-4510s NetworkManager[932]: <info>  [1608659339.0083] manager: startup complete
dic 22 18:50:59 hellnhell-HP-ProBook-4510s NetworkManager[932]: <info>  [1608659459.3603] agent-manager: agent[ad45a090be0fe1cf,:1.>
dic 22 18:52:02 hellnhell-HP-ProBook-4510s NetworkManager[932]: <info>  [1608659522.8834] policy: auto-activating connection 'iPhon>
dic 22 18:52:02 hellnhell-HP-ProBook-4510s NetworkManager[932]: <info>  [1608659522.8856] device (wlp3s0): Activation: starting con>
```

So please help!!!

Comment: Please provide log messages from NetworkManager using `journalctl -b -u NetworkManager -u wpa_supplicant` after this happens.

Comment: I've editied the question with the info. Thx!!

Comment: That doesn't look like a complete log -- it's just the oldest messages (while the interesting ones are newest), and the line ends are trimmed. Dump the log to a file (using `> nmlog.txt`) and see what you can find in there...

Comment: Did you (or someone) change anything in the configuration of the router/access point? Or was any software updated just before it stopped working? Please [edit] your question to add this information.

Comment: I didn’t change anything of the router/access point... And the problem starts before I updated ubuntu. Either I can connect to the network with other devices without problems...  Now I’m using my iPhone as hotspot in the laptop correctly.

Comment: @user1686 i had like 178 lines of info when i execute the journalctl , know added to a .txt file, but i don't know what is exactly what i have to look for... i'm "new" in linux so i'm like a little bit lost... if you could tell mewhat i need to know or to paste in the question, or just everything?

Comment: I’ve just found this error “failed to open /run/network/-ifstate”

Answer (score 1):

Everything is solved. I don’t know exactly what the issue was. I’ve get this messagae, "Reason: 15=4WAY_HANDSHAKE_TIMEOUT" so I tried this commands:

‘sudo modprobe -r ath9k
sudo modprobe ath9k nohwcrypt=1’

And everything seems to be ok now.
Thx for the interest